# Creating a gdbus object (sim card)

Tags: drivers, d-bus, modem

I have a wwan modem in which I can insert a sim card, 
via gdbus introspect I am a ble to retrieve every information I would need to simulate that sim card (Identifier, imsi, operator identifier and name).
I would like to be able to create a dbus object that would make my life easier so that I won't have to take the sim in and out and no missing phone calls which my modem doesn't support. So is this possible ?

The second part of my question which has not much to do with the former is : why can't I send AT commands via mmcli even though ModemManager is started in debug mode ? I have the answer:

```
GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.ModemManager1.Error.Core.Connected: No AT port available to run command
```